# I need an fstab example for archivemount (want to umount without my password)

Tags: mount, backup, fstab

I am using archivemount to mount one of several tar.bz files in Ubuntu. It works very nicely for me.

I mount and umount frequently (I'm in a testing phase). I want a solution that will allow me to umount without typing in my password. Here's my current script:

```
ARCHIVE=$(zenity --file-selection --filename=/share/);
archivemount $ARCHIVE /media/Archive/
echo "when finished use: sudo umount /media/Archive/"
```

My goal is to simply be able to `umount` quickly and easily without typing my password. I understand that adding an fstab entry will do the trick, but I cannot find the correct format for the fstab entry when using archivemount.

Comment: Looks like `archivemount` is a fuse-based system, try `fusermount -u /media/Archive`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`archivemount` is a fuse-based system (like sshfs, among others), so you can unmount it as a regular user (at least the one who mounted it) using

```
fusermount -u /media/Archive
```

Comment: When I tried that I got an error saying,
"fusermount: entry for /home/enkouyami/Test not found in /etc/mtab"